# Alternative IDE supporting debugging for Google App Engine in Python (Eclipse + PyDev no debug support on SDK 1.7.6+)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, ide, breakpoints

I'm developing on GAE-Python 2.7 using Eclipse+PyDev as IDE. Since GAE SDK 1.7.6 (March 2013), where Google "broke" support for breakpoints*, I've been using the old dev server to continue debugging the application I'm working on.

However, Google will drop support of the old dev server as of July 2013 and, since I do not expect a prompt solution for this on PyDev (I've seen no activity so far about this), I would like to look for an alternative IDE to still being able to do debugging.

I know that one of the possible options is to go for PyCharm (initial license of 89€+VAT and 59€+VAT each year to continue receiving upgrades), but I would like to know how other people is (will be) addressing this problem and what are the current alternatives to PyCharm

*I would like to clarify the sentence "Google broke support for breakpoints": In SDK 1.7.6+, Google started using stdin/stdout in the new dev server for doing IPC and this leaves no chances to even do debugging with pdb. Google claims that they have created the hooks for tool vendors to support debugging (as PyCharm did) but, in my opinion, they "broke" debugging by forcing people to move away from the IDE they were initially recommending due to an architectural decision (I'm not an expert, but they could have used the native IPC mechanisms included in Python instead of using stdin/stdout).

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I'm running Eclipse+Pydev for MacOSX, so please, also mention your OS compatibility in your alternatives/solutions.

Comment: Just to note, PyDev 2.8.0 is now supporting the new hooks on Google App Engine, so, debugging should be working again. See release details at: http://pydev.org/

Answer (score 1):

I posted this in google groups a while back. I can run debugging in Boa Constructor using remote debugging.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/google-appengine/Boa/google-appengine/-m00Qz4Vc7U

I am pretty sure it would be trivial to make winpdb work with remote debugging as well, though I haven't tried it (I don't use winpdb ;-)

If any other debug environments support similiar remote debugging facilities it shouldn't be too hard to get them going.

There a screen shot of Boa debugging in action here [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/debugging$20Boa/google-appengine/ZHHkwr3ok8c/btDno8oPYyAJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/debugging%2420Boa/google-appengine/ZHHkwr3ok8c/btDno8oPYyAJ)

T

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of PyDev (2.8.1) supports GAE debugging. However, "Edit and Continue Debugging or Interactive Debugging" feature seems to have stopped working.